Make global variables become local variables
I'm creating a program to calculate the price of a telecommunications package based on call history. Here is main function.
from math import ceil

prev_date = None
expen_minutes_used = 0

def calculate_call_cost(row):
    
    global prev_date, expen_minutes_used 

    if prev_date is None or row['data of call'].date() != prev_date:
        prev_date = row['data of call'].date() 
        expen_minutes_used = 0

    expen_minutes = 0
    if expen_minutes_used < 5:
        expen_minutes = min(5 - expen_minutes_used, ceil(row['Duration in second'] / 60))
                        
        expen_minutes_used += expen_minutes 

    cheap_minutes = ceil(row['Duration in second'] / 60) - expen_minutes
                    
    
    cost = cheap_minutes * 0.40 + expen_minutes * 3.95
    return cost

calls_data_sorted['Cost of tariff'] = calls_data_sorted.apply(calculate_call_cost, axis = 1) 
total_cost2 = calls_data_sorted['Cost of tariff'].sum()
calls_data_sorted

Please tell me is there any way to change those global varibales into local varibles.

your call to the function is in the commented line. How are you actually calling the function?

You have global cheap_minutes_used but never use that variable.

Put the state that needs to persist between calls in a dictionary. Pass this as an argument to calculate_call_cost(), and the function can update the dictionary.
from math import ceil

state_dict = {'prev_date': None, 'expen_minutes_used': 0}

def calculate_call_cost(row, state: dict):
    if state['prev_date'] is None or row['data of call'].date() != state['prev_date']:
        state['prev_date'] = row['data of call'].date() 
        state['expen_minutes_used'] = 0

    expen_minutes = 0
    if state['expen_minutes_used'] < 5:
        expen_minutes = min(5 - state['expen_minutes_used'], ceil(row['Duration in second'] / 60))
                        
        state['expen_minutes_used'] += expen_minutes 

    cheap_minutes = ceil(row['Duration in second'] / 60) - expen_minutes
                    
    
    cost = cheap_minutes * 0.40 + expen_minutes * 3.95
    return cost

calls_data_sorted['Cost of tariff'] = calls_data_sorted.apply(lambda row: calculate_call_cost(row, state_dict), axis = 1) 
total_cost2 = calls_data_sorted['Cost of tariff'].sum()

You could also make a class with calculate_call_cost() as a method. The variables that need to persist can be attributes of the class.

could you please go to detail about making class with calculate_call_cost() as a method?

I thought about writing that in the answer, I decided it was more work than I wanted to put into this.

But it should be pretty easy for you to do with a dataclass.

@Barmar It's still global, You're passing a global dictionary as a parameter that eventually sets it as local, but also as global variable, It wasn't changed, It's became both.

@EdenRefaelov But you can use different dictionaries in different loops, so the problem with using a specific global variable in the function is avoided.

@Barmar The solution you've suggested using the same dictionary (same address/object) by reference.
When you change state: dict the state_dict will be changed also.

@EdenRefaelov Of course. As I understand it, they want to progagate these running totals from one row to the next in the apply() loop. So they need something that persists between calls. Encapsulating it in a mutable object is better than hard-coding global variables.
